# Connectionstring in windowsservice

Tags: asp.net

My web application's webconfig file contain following connectionstring.

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="TestConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=ServerIp;Initial Catalog=databasename;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=userid;Password=password"
   providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

May I know what meaning of Persist Security Info?.What is purpose of it in this case?

In my windows service, class file contain following connectionstring.

```
connectionString="Server=ServerIp;Database=databasename;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;Integrated Security=false;User Id=userid;Password=password"
```

I want to add appconfig file for connection and replace above one.Does I need to mention provider name?Here is sample one which I am going to write in app.config file.

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="SampleConnectionstring" connectionString="Server=ServerIp;Database=databasename;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;Integrated Security=false;User Id=userid;Password=password" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

what is meaning of MultipleActiveResultSets?Why it is used here?

Answer (score 0):

From MSDN:  Multiple Active Result Sets (MARS) is a feature that works with SQL Server to allow the execution of multiple batches on a single connection. When MARS is enabled for use with SQL Server, each command object used adds a session to the connection.

With regards to Persist Security Info:  When set to false or no (strongly recommended), security-sensitive information, such as the password, is not returned as part of the connection if the connection is open or has ever been in an open state. Resetting the connection string resets all connection string values including the password. Recognized values are true, false, yes, and no.

More information can be found here:  [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectionstring(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectionstring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Also, here's a great resource for connection strings:  http://www.connectionstrings.com/